# Adding an EventListener to a form, running a function on submit on whatever child <input> in the form actually called the submit

Tags: javascript, html

http://jsfiddle.net/twG6R/8/

Ignore the fact that this is a completely toy application. If there is NO time in which this is the right way to do things however, let me know.

So, I have a `<form>` with two `<input>` fields in it. I have an eventListener stuck to the `<form>` listening for a "submit" event. I then want to run a function which does some stuff to the number the user put in either input1 or input2. User types a number in say, input2, hits enter, and the function calls on this.id, but returns the id of the form, not the actual input box that is a child of the form.

What can I do?

EDIT: Should I look at all the child elements of `form` somehow and test each child to see if there's something in it, and then call `alertGrade` with the non-empty children as a parameter?

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="number" id="score1" value="" min="0" max="100">
  <input type="number" id="score2" value="" min="0" max="100">
  <input type="submit" value="Grade">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function alertGrade(elementID) {
  var score = document.getElementById(elementID).value;
  var grade = calculateGrade(score);
  alert("Score of " + score + ": " + grade);
}

function loaded() {
    document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit",
            function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // this.id will show "form"
                alert(this.id);
                alertGrade(this.id);},
                false);
}

window.addEventListener("load", loaded, false);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
function loaded() {
    document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit", function() {
        for (var i = 0, j = this.childNodes.length; i < j, i++) {
            if (this.childNodes[i].value !== "") {
                alertGrade(this.childNodes[i].id);
                return;
            }
        }
        alert("Please type something");
    }, false);
}
```

This will loop through each of the childNodes of the form and if it finds something has the value, it will send its value to alertGrade. If it does not find anything, it will alert the user to type something.

But a word of caution: Everytime the user clicks submit button, the page refreshes (atleast on my browser) and you may not get what you want.

Comment: Hey, nice. I believe your caution can be fixed by making `function()` into `function(event)` and adding `event.preventDefault()` in the body.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in my code due to which the user always get the `alert` message, even if he has typed something. I have updated the code with the fix. It was due the fact the I broke the `for` loop instead of returning the function

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Have you tried `event.srcElement`?</strike>  Because I did, and frustratingly it did not work as expected.

The simplest solution I could come up without using native JavaScript was to add a `keypress` listener to the input fields, and use that to catch and manually handle the `return` keypress, like:

```
<input type="number"
      onkeypress="return inputKeyPress(event, this);"
      id="score1"
      value=""
      min="0" max="100">

function inputKeyPress(evt, field) {
    var evt  = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);

    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
        alertGrade(field.id);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/q8Eqn/

Comment: That's convoluted enough to lend credence to my theory that I'm just going about this completely the wrong way.

Comment: @Austin - Yes, have you considered just implementing your `onsubmit` listener so that it looks at both input fields, and then just picks whichever one has a value (or grades them both if both are filled in)?  That would certainly be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other respondents, I also don't know if there's a way to do precisely what you want. But you can find out when an input field changes with the `onchange` event (slightly less involved than reading each keypress):

```
document.getElementById("score1").addEventListener("change",
        function(event) {
            alert(this.id);
        }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want value of score1 or score2.Then you should pass id "score1" and "score2" in your function call of alertGrade()

when you call alrtGrade(this.id).It is actually passing the id of form.

OR

when you call getElementById,the id should be either "score1" or "score2"

Comment: Right, that's what I want, but I have no way of knowing whether `score1` or `score2` is the one that actually has any data in it.

Comment: For that,you have to check both like.  var score1=document.getElementById('score1').value;  var score2 =document.getElementBYId('score2').value;  then apply your if else logic.